# Attendance application useing Qrcode c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, time-and-attendance

i have been searching everywhere for an example to create Attendance system using Qrcode. As Employee having cards with Qrcode with their details like Employee Id, Name, Position.

1. Fixed Qrcode Scanner/Webcam attached with Computer ([Device like](http://www.denso-wave.com/en/adcd/product/type/scanner.html))
2. once user shows his card to Scanner/Webcam his data gets submitted to database as in/out with time and date.
3. Attendance Reporting by Employee id for in/out record from database.

i have found many example to RFID Attendance system like finger print, but didn't find answer/example to qrcode.

Thanks

Comment: Show what code you have tried.  According to that website, there is keyboard interface software that you would need to download and install.  My guess is that your program would just see the input from the device as if it were typed on a keyboard, so you can use standard events (TextChanged, KeyDown, etc.) with the device.

Comment: Its just the same with barcode scanner. just have a sample textbox and go for event like TextChanged, if textbox is triggered then automatically fire your code for in/out of the employees. Go to this [website](http://www.barcodelib.com/net_barcode_reader/barcodes/qrcode.html) for download of the dlls.